# MediaPlayerのI2S出力に関して

Tags: spresense

MediaPlayerにおいて、I2S出力はサポートされているでしょうか？
試しに、thePlayer->activate()の引数に AS_SETPLAYER_OUTPUTDEVICE_I2SOUTPUT を設定してもヘッドホンから出力されました。

AudioClassを使ってのI2S出力は成功しています。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
ご回答が遅くなり、誠に申し訳ありません。

ご指摘の通り、MediaPlayerではI2S出力の対応をしていませんでした。

最新のライブラリ version 1.1.3 にて、MediaPlayerでのI2S出力に対応いたしました。
ライブラリのアップデートは、Arduino IDE の「ボードマネージャ」で行ってください。

どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。